# how to transfer block device over unencrypted tcp port 22?

Tags: linux, backup, file-transfer

I need to transfer disk image from old server that has only port 22 open and it has too weak cpu for any reasonable ssh transfer speed. I tried:

- ssh - painfully slow, beyond practicality
- rsync - can't send block device
- rsh - I can't seem to find option to change server port to 22
- nc like below:

client:

```
nc <ip> 22 > /backup/path/sda.img
```

server:

```
dd if=dev/sda bs=8M | nc -l -p 22
```

but it doesn't seem to work as expected (at all). Other ports can't be opened and no additional software can be installed on server and server has blocked outgoing connections.

I'm running out of options ._.

Comment: Why a  disk image? Done well, you just tar the filesystem via nc

Comment: Port 22 is almost certainly ssh. And why are you assuming slow transfer speeds a CPU-limited? You have no evidence that any other protocol goes faster.  The sooner you get started, the sooner it'll be done....

Comment: Do you get any error messages? Did you mean to type `/dev/sda` rather than `dev/sda`? (Those would refer to the same file if your current directory is `/`.)

Comment: Reminder: you can check on the status of `dd` with a `CTRL-t` or by sending the `dd` process a USR1 just to see what _is_ happening.

Comment: In the end I managed to use `nbd` and it works. 22 was exactly because it was `ssh` so I could shut down ssh daemon and get the only port open in firewall. Indeed it's not bottlenecking on CPU. I don't know what is bottleneck with `ssh` but connection between machines is 1G and disks are much faster than 20MB/s. I checked that. No there was no error with `nc` it just didn't send anything. When I typed something in client nc it appeared on server screen also when I typed on server it didn't appear on client so pipe seemed to work but disk data was not transferred properly idk why. 0 disk i/o

Comment: have you tried either installing a second drive into the old server and copying to that (with dd, rsync, or whatever) OR removing the drive from the old server and installing it in another machine to copy from?

Comment: Have you tried using a very weak but very fast cipher for SSH?  Only do this if you either don't care about security or are extremely confident that only you are on the wire:  `ssh -c arcfour`.

Comment: Is `/dev/sda` the only hard drive on your server? If so, I would probably recommend using a live CD or USB stick for this operation, so that you can make sure that you're not trying to transfer the contents of a drive with a mounted filesystem. Otherwise, could you try disabling the firewall? It could be affecting network connectivity.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

Remote side :

```
# nc -l -p 22 > sda.img
```

Client side :

```
# dd if=/dev/sda bs=8M | nc -w 3 remote_host 22
```

Comment: But I wanted the other way around. copy sda from remote host to image on local machine. Because server has blocked outgoing connections it can't `nc` to workstation with backup NAS hooked up. So device that has original `/dev/sda` has to use `nc -l`, not the other one